# Connecting to database error during mocha unit test

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, mocha.js, knex.js

I'm building an app using node.js + express, postgresql for database, and mocha + chai for testing. I am trying to test an API that makes a database query. However, when I run my test I keep getting the error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user "m11111"
error: Error: Pool was destroyed
```

Here's my test file:

```
require('dotenv').load();
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../../app');
var should = chai.should();
var knex = require('../../models/database').knex;


chai.use(chaiHttp);

it('should get all projects', function(done) {
  chai.request(server)
    .get('/api/projects')
    .end(function(err, res){
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.json;
      res.body.should.be.a('array');
      done();
    });
});
```

My API that i'm testing:

```
api.get('/api/projects', function(req, res) {
    console.log('get projects hit'); //this console logs out
    knex('projects').select()
        .then(function(data) {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
});
```

And here's my database connection string:

```
require('dotenv').load();

module.exports = {
    knex: require('knex')({
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT
        },
        pool: {
            min: 0,
            max: 7
        },
        searchPath: process.env.DB_SEARCHPATH
    })
};
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you passing those environment variables into your test command?

Comment: i included the `require('dotenv').load();` in my test file.. my test command is `mocha ajax` so i'm not sure how to specifically pass the environment variables into my command

Comment: well then are the fields in your .env file assigned values? Also in anything on a unix based system, to pass env variables you do `ENV_VAR=value <command> <arguments>`

Comment: Here's a sample field in my .env file: `APP_PORT = 3000` @ChristianGrabowski

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but if I recall it should be `APP_PORT=3000`, note no spaces.

Comment: i just realized - i also get an additional error: `{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }` - that might explain why the environment variables aren't passing through...

Comment: Any idea on how I can prevent it? I included `require('dotenv').load();` in my test file, my api file, as well as my connection string file - which I thought would pass on the environment variables..

Comment: I'm guessing custom path, `require('dotenv').config({path: '/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'});` should fix that.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!!!!!!!!